# How to check whether all elements in list are numeric?

Tags: scala

I have a data in this form, this is basically a huge data.

```
val data: Array[(Int, Iterable[String])] =
  Array(
    (34,List("sdkfj",7, 2, 5, 3, 1, 9, 2, 1, 4)),
    (4,List(7, 14, 4, 5, 11, 9, 5, 4, 1))
  )
```

I want to apply a function say `isNumeric` on the iterable items which should return me the output in the following way

```
Array((34,false), (4,true))
```

Basically, I want a `false` if any element in the list is not numeric, otherwise `true`.

I have tried this function

```
def isNumeric(input: String): Boolean = input.forall(_.isDigit)
```

But in this case I get a list of booleans whereas I want a single boolean result for the entire list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to call `.forall` on the inner list :

```
scala> def isNumeric(input: String): Boolean = input.forall(_.isDigit)
isNumeric: (input: String)Boolean

scala> val a:Array[(Int,List[String])] = Array((34,List("sdkfj","7", "2", "5", "3", "1", "9", "2", "1", "4")), (4,List("7", "14", "4", "5", "11", "9", "5", "4", "1")))
a: Array[(Int, List[String])] = Array((34,List(sdkfj, 7, 2, 5, 3, 1, 9, 2, 1, 4)),
                                      (4, List(7, 14, 4, 5, 11, 9, 5, 4, 1)))

scala> a.map { case (k, l) => (k, l.forall(isNumeric)) }
res0: Array[(Int, Boolean)] = Array((34,false), (4,true))
```

**EDIT**

If you want to skip the validation for certain elements, you can use `.filter` before using `.forall` (running the validations only on the sublist) :

```
scala> val a:Array[(Int,List[String])] = Array((34,List("NA","7", "3")))
a: Array[(Int, List[String])] = Array((34,List(NA, 7, 3)))

// Not sure what an NA is, so...
scala> def isNA(s:String) = s == "NA"
isNA: (s: String)Boolean

// Using .filterNot here since you want to exclude all `NA`s
// You can also use .filter(!isNA(_)) 
// or .withFilter(!isNA(_)) which should be faster/more efficient
scala> a.map{ case (k, l) => (k, l.filterNot(isNA).forall(isNumeric)) }
res0: Array[(Int, Boolean)] = Array((34,true))
```

Note that you could also change the `.isNumeric` method to `.isNumericOrNA` (thereby skipping the need for a `filter`), although it might be a bit confusing, depending on what `NA` is.

NB:  See the [Scala API](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List) for an explanation of the differences between `.filter` and `.withFilter`.

Comment: Thanks Marth...this is working fine ..all wrong i was doing is using map instead of forall that you mentioned...basically because i am new to scala...also in my dataset i have NA where the value is missing...i want to exclude the comparison for NA's. Is it possible to add some filter within forall so that it skips isNumeric on NA's ?